# Camelbak safe to use after cleaning for the first time in 4 years?

Tags: backpacking, drinking-water, hydration-bladders

I'm going on a 2-day backpacking trip. I have a CamelBak that I haven't used in 4 years. I saw zero mold in it, it smelled fine. I flushed it a few times, including the lines and mouthpiece, with near boiling hot water. Then I filled it with tap water. I drank a little, it tasted fine.

Should it be safe to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, you should be perfectly fine to use it. If there was no mold after storing it and before cleaned it out, I wouldn't worry about it.

Camelbak's [official cleaning instructions](https://www.camelbak.com/en/customer-service/help-center/care-cleaning/product-cleaning/how-to-clean-reservoir)  say it safe to use even if you had gotten mold inside of it after following their [instructions](https://www.camelbak.com/en/customer-service/help-center/care-cleaning/product-cleaning/how-to-clean-reservoir) (although it still might be stained).

In short, you should be fine.